# Function of: if(/(file|http).*/.test(url)) { }

Tags: javascript, regex

I am wondering what this technique is called and what it does. It seems to be validating some regular expression on the variable `url`. I am customizing another persons code:

```
var url = document.getElementById("editorURL").value;   
if(/(file|http).*/.test(url)) {

}
```

Maybe someone has a link to an article that explains this a bit more in-depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regular expression checking whether `url` begins with either `file` or `http`, an effort to make sure the value entered is a proper URL pointing to a resource that can be opened in a browser.

Seeing as it fails to check for the subsequent `://` part (and would for example match `filexyz` or `httphttphttp`), I would say it is not perfect.

More on the `test()` method at [W3Schools](http://wwww.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp).

> The test() method tests for a match in a string.
>
> This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and recommendation on improving it further :D

Answer (score 3):

It's called "validating" (!), and it's meant to check that "editorURL" contains a URL containing the word "file" or "http". It's not that good of a regex actually, but better than nothing. A start would be to at least check that file or http are at the *beginning* of the URL, not as it is now anywhere within it.

```
/^(file|http).*/.test(url)
```

This is also only client-side validation, meant to give the user instant feedback on the validation. You should have at least the same rules, possible even stricter, on the server-side as well. The server-side validation are for catching errors before they reach your database/data-layer, but also to protect against crackers (anyone can work around the client-side validation if they want to, so *never* trust data from the client).

Edit: My pattern above means (step by step):

- `/` this is the beginning of the
  regex pattern
- `^` start matching from the beginning
  of the text (beginning of the `url`
  variable. This is missing in original pattern)
- `(` start a sub-pattern (pattern within
  the pattern - mostly meant for
  grouping)
- `file|http` match literally *file* OR
  *http*
- `)` end of sub-pattern
- `.` any character
- `*` repeat the last character zero or more times (in this case "any character(s)")
- `/` end of regex pattern

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive breakdown of the regexp.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially: `if (url matches some_expression) { /* do something * }`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: I do understand if statements but the question concerned the expression and the test() function. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hence the link explaining the regexp object, its syntax and methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(file|http).*/
```

This is a regular expression that matches any string beginning with file or http, so in this case, any URL using those protocols.

```
regex.test(string)
```

This is a function that tests if the regex matches the string and returns a boolean, so together they make is a very basic url validation method.

Answer (score 1):

I find [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to be the best all-around reference for regular expressions. Their tutorial goes all the way from simple to complex and they also include info about what works in the various flavours of regular expression engine.

Answer (score 0):

It's an attempt to check whether the url starts with file:// or http://. It's based on an incorrect assumption, though. The author assumes that the `test()` method only returns true if it matches the whole string, but it returns true if it matches *any part* of the string. For example, this evaluates to true:

```
/(file|http).*/.test(' a test file')
```

You could get rid of the `.*` part and it would still get the same results for any given string.

Since the person who wrote it got this wrong, there's probably other things that are wrong, too. I suggest rewriting bits an pieces, after dissecting their functionality. It will be much less frustrating than making tiny changes to buggy code. Good luck!